# How to make button appear when dropdown option is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, button

```
document.getElementById("SameDifferent").addEventListener('click',function () {
    start(game.SameDifferent);
    document.getElementById("instructions").innerHTML = "Press S for 'same' and D for 'different'";
}  );
```

So right now, when I click toggle the function to start the game, I have instructions appear by changing the innerHTML in my html file. I want two buttons to pop up instead, however, that say "Same" and "Different". I'm almost a complete beginner at HTML/Javascript, so not sure how to do this. I can make the button appear constantly, but I am confused on how to toggle it in the js file.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084852/toggle-class-on-click-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the button to hidden like below:

```
document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
```

To show:

```
document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi consider this HTML:

```
<button onclick="toggle()">Click Me</button>
<div id="tggle">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

It displays a button (toogle), that shows the div with ID `tggle`, here's the javascript to toggle it:

```
function toggle() {
    var x = document.getElementById("tggle");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```